# A successful StringReplace with an error message

Tags: warning-messages, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

An example of `StringReplace` and `RegularExpression` :

```
StringReplace["czAB26fgsgAB5ac77bd", RegularExpression["AB[0-9]"] -> "XXX"]
"czXXX6fgsgXXXac77bd"
```

The above example is easy.

Now to get "czAB2XXX6fgsgAB5XXXac77bd", I tried

```
StringReplace["czAB26fgsgAB5ac77bd", v : RegularExpression["AB[0-9]"] -> (v <> "XXX")]
"czAB2XXX6fgsgAB5XXXac77bd"
```

I succeeded to get the result, but with an error message :

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in v<>XXX.
```

What is the reason for the error message? What is the correct method? (not showing the error message)

Comment: Replace `->` by `:>`?

Comment: Thank you, I understood. If you execute `a<>b`, then MMA will say a,b must be string.  The question can be understood in the similar context.

Comment: Exactly. With `->` it will evaluate `v <> ...` immediately, when `v` is just a symbol and not yet a string, and give the warning. With `:>` it will evaluate `v <> ...` only later, when `v` is an actual string.

Comment: For the benefit of page visitors and using  Mathematica's `StringExpression` syntax: `StringReplace["czAB26fgsgAB5ac77bd", 
 k : ("AB" ~~ DigitCharacter) :> ToString@k <> "XXX"]`